# File Suffix in R

Tags: r, file, naming

Is there a file suffix convention in R?

I've seen `file.r` and `file.R`.

Is either suffix preferable when creating a file?

Comment: While there is no "standard", it's much easier to spot a big ol' R at the end of a file than a little one when looking at a long list of file names.

Comment: FWIW, the `Source R code...` dialogue has only `.R` as the extension type

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both the [Google](https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Rguide.xml#filenames) and [Wickhamite](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/style.html) style-guides prefer `.R` (I happen to agree with them) but there's actually no standardised R style guide (i.e., equivalent to Python's PEP8). This has led to [quite a few idiosyncrasies](http://journal.r-project.org/archive/2012-2/RJournal_2012-2_Baaaath.pdf). Generally-speaking, I'd say to go with `.R`.

Answer (score 4):

As from [Google's R Style Guide](https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Rguide.xml):

```
File names should end in .R and, of course, be meaningful.
GOOD: predict_ad_revenue.R 
BAD: foo.R
```

So `.R` is preferable.

Comment: Are you sure you've read what you just copy/pasted? You both "GOOD" and "BAD" have same suffix. This link talks about meaningfull file names rather than suffixes

Comment: @DavidArenburg are you sure you've read what I've copy/pasted? It is definitely said `be meaningful` there. But `foo.R` is not very much meaningful, uh?

Comment: @AndyKorneyev, David's comment referred to the fact that what you copied refers _exclusively_ on file naming conventions (in your case "predict_ad_revenue" vs "foo") but doesn't answer the OP's question (should I use file.r or file.R).

Comment: @beginneR Doesn't it definitely said `File names should end in .R` there?

Comment: Nvm, my mistake, though I don't think Google way is the *right* way. It's just another opinion among others. It seems Olivers answer is more complete (and also provides this same link among others)